# Chrome extension manifest CSP ignored on public page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy

I've set my extension's CSP to allow loading from `localhost` (in theory):

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://localhost:* ws://localhost:* https://*.mysite.com; object-src 'self'",
```

I have a `web_accessible_resource` that attempts to load and execute a remote script:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Sign in</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="./auth.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The (simplified) content of `auth.js`:

```
(function(doc, script) {
  script = doc.createElement('script')
  script.type = 'text/javascript'
  script.async = true
  script.src = 'https://localhost:3333/remote-server/auth.js'
  doc.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script)
}(document))
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
Refused to load the script 'https://localhost:3333/remote-server/auth.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'".
```

Which doesn't seem to be respecting the extension's CSP. I've tried adding the following header to the HTML directly, but still no joy.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://localhost:* ws://localhost:* https://*.mysite.com">
```

Is there some other place that I need to indicate the CSP?

---

**UPDATE**

Changing the resource's HTML to load the remote script directly did not solve the problem either:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Sign in</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://localhost:* ws://localhost:* https://*.mysite.com">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="https://localhost:3333/remote-server/auth.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Still results in:

```
Refused to load the script 'https://localhost:3333/remote-server/auth.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'".
```

Which still has no reference to the content of the `<meta>` tag

---

**UPDATE 2**

The page is loaded via

```
chrome.windows.create({
  url: 'chrome-extension://my-extension/auth.html',
  type: 'popup',
  height: 680,
  width: 500
}, (windw) => console.log(windw))
```

Comment: So the question remains, how do I allow remote loading in `web_accessible_resource`s then? If the extension's CSP doesn't apply, what does?

Comment: Did you figure this out? What's the best way to disable CSP on the main webpage? I found this source but my attempts have failed. This only seems to work after a full page reload. Thanks!

https://github.com/PhilGrayson/chrome-csp-disable/blob/master/background.js

Answer (score 0):

HTTP Headers will take precedence, if you have those, meta tags will be pretty much ignored.

The thing is, google chrome is complying with the main webpage headers. And those will take precedence, you would have to disable the CSP for the page you're trying to load your scripts from.